# how to make Several facebook links on site to open in facebook native app and auto generate the facebook profile or page numeric id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have the below android code for Facebook link to open in the native Facebook application. it is working fine but only for the profile id which is given here `url = "fb://profile/100012746891816";` .
Please if somebody can help and edit my code and make it working for several Facebook profiles or pages on the website and generates the Facebook id automatically.

here is how im linking through php `<a href="<?php echo "http://facebook.com/".$fbk; ?>">` the `$fbk` contains Facebook page or profile name.

```
if (url.contains("http://facebook.com")) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    try {
        url = "fb://profile/100012746891816";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: any help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
private static final String FB_BASE = "facebook.com/";

public void openFacebookProfile(String profileUrl){
    try{
        Uri uri = null;

        int versionCode = getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0)
                .versionCode;

        if(versionCode >= 3002850)
            uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + profileUrl);
        else {
            String profileId = profileUrl.substring(profileUrl.indexOf(FB_BASE) + FB_BASE.length());

            uri = Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + profileId);
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    }
    catch(Throwable e){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(profileUrl)));
    }
}
```

As long as the URL contains "facebook.com/", it should strip the profile ID from the end (assuming there's no trailing data), and then open through the correct native FB platform, or default to the web.

Comment: FB profile and pages URLs have the same structure, so there's no way to differentiate between the 2 unless you explicitly tell it which type it is, which is a bit beyond the scope of the original question, but what I've provided should more than point you in the right direction (hint: look at the else statement)